# Could the use of exotic matter be removed from Alcubierre Drives?

Tags: alcubierre-drive, spacetime

Im wondering if it is possible to create an [Alcubierre Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) without any exotic matter. To clarify: What if you take normal flat space-time and you lower a section of it to far below the standard. Possibly by filling the area with a very heavy homogeneous gas. And to simulate the negative curvature, you take away the gas in those areas. In that perspective it is still all positive curvature but relative to objects in the lowered space-time, it contains negative curvature. I understand that constructing this would be impractical and difficult, but much more possible than negative matter right? Well would that work?

Extraneous Information That May Or May Not Be Grounded In Reality:
Could that gas, on small scale testing, be a heavy Bose-Einstein condensate? Or just a cloud of super-cold entangled particles?

[PBS Space Time](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7_gcs09iThXybpVgjHZ_7g) informative video on the Alcubierre Drive by astrophysicist Matt O'Dowd:

Comment: I think [this experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White%E2%80%93Juday_warp-field_interferometer) was designed to explore that very idea.

Comment: Definitely not practical for space travel. You'd need to fill the whole distance between the origin and destination with that ultra-dense gas and manipulate its density dynamically.

Comment: @SF. the "warp highway" https://youtu.be/94ed4v_T6YM?t=277

Comment: You can propell a ship this way, but I believe in order to achieve "faster than light" speeds, you need something with true negative mass.